# Parse.Cloud.afterSave for sending push notifications not working from Heroku server

Tags: ios, heroku, push-notification, migration, parse-server

I did the migration, from Parse to Heroku and everything went smooth. At this point I didn't have any cloud code or push notifications set up on Parse. When I was done with the migration I begin to implement cloud code to handle push notification every time I save a new text message, but the Parse.Cloud.afterSave method is not running. I know main.js is working because if I implement

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) {
res.success('Hi');
});
```

I get "Hi" return to my console in Xcode, but for some reason Parse.Cloud.afterSave does nothing. I also know my Parse.Cloud.afterSave code is correct because it's that same code I use on another app through parse though. What am I missing?

Here in my index.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var api = new ParseServer({
databaseURI: databaseUri || '',

cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
appId: process.env.APP_ID || '',
masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '',
fileKey: 'XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX', // file key from parse
serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || '',

push: {
ios: {
pfx: '/Users/alexcruz/Desktop/Certificates.p12', // The filename of private key and certificate in PFX or PKCS12 format from disk
bundleId: 'com.daps.DapsPush', // The bundle identifier associate with your app
production: false // Specifies which environment to connect to: Production (if true) or Sandbox
}
}
});

var app = express();

// Serve static assets from the /public folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.status(200).send('Make sure to star the parse-server repo on GitHub!');
});

// There will be a test page available on the /test path of your server url
// Remove this before launching your app
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/test.html'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

// This will enable the Live Query real-time server
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

Here is my main.js file

```
//Push Notification for messages that are received
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("MXTMessage", function(request) {
  var messageText = request.object.get('message');
  var usersReceived = request.object.get('receiver');
  var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
      pushQuery.equalTo('user', usersReceived);
      pushQuery.notEqualTo('user', currentUser);
        Parse.Push.send({
            where: pushQuery, // Set our Installation query
            data: {
              alert: "New message: " + messageText
             }
            }, {
      success: function() {
      // Push was successful
          },
      error: function(error) {
        throw "Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message;
          }
            });
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I am not allowed to comment, I'm going to have to put this in an answer, but just treat it as a comment:

Did you verify the function itself is actually never being called e.g. by adding a console.log at the beginning of the function, or could it be that push itself is not working (you can check that by sending pushes via REST API Calls)? For example, push seems to be broken in parse-server 2.2.0, I had to downgrade to 1.6.0 to get it working.

Workaround could be to create a cloud code function for sending the push and have this function explicitly called by the clients after the message has been saved on the server.

Also you should check this: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/301 as you are using Parse.User.current() in your code.

Also, I get the impression that parse-server is not really stable at this time. I experience many bugs using parse-server and Heroku that the app running on parse.com does not have.